# Windows Subsystem Linux VSCode path

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have made a mess with trying to install Visual Studio Code on my Windows Subsystem Linux.

Before I get into that I was able to use the terminal command `code .` to open VSCode in the current directory, this worked with cmd, bash, zsh or fish

Since trying to install VSCode on my WSL [which doesn't work just yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2293) I haven't been able to use the `code .` command.

So I did a `whereis code` then found this:

```
code: /usr/bin/code /usr/share/code /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS 
Code/bin/code /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code.cmd
```

So, I'm guessing installing VSCode for Linux added in `/usr/bin/code` and `/usr/share/code` which I'm also guessing is what's being called when I do my `code .` command?

Then `ls -la /usr/bin/` and I find this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          24 Oct  9 19:38 code -> /usr/share/code/bin/code*
```

This is where I'm a bit confused now, I'd like to get it back to pointing at the `/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code` and `/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code.cmd` I guess but I'm a bit confused as to what to do next.

Any pointers greatly appreciated :ok_hand:

Thanks

Comment: I used `sudo rm /usr/bin/code` which seems to have done it

From these guides:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-remove-delete-symbolic-softlink-command/

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the symlinks created in `/usr/bin/code` and `/usr/share/code`.

You don't need to add new symlinks in WSL to make code run: VSCode installs a code.sh file in its folder that's accessible on your path since we append the Windows path to your Linux path in WSL.

Comment: I removed `/usr/bin/code` but I couldn't remove `/usr/share/code` it works now though.

Comment: Can you explain what a symlink is?

Comment: @spences10 a sybmlink is a symbolic link. It's a special type of file in a directory that points to a file in a different directory. When you open, run or copy the symbolic link the OS opens the real file it points to instead.